# To get columns data like the data I list with foreach

Tags: php, foreach, survey

I have prepared a survey script questions and answer options with points like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.
I want to view the user's responses to a poll. The questions are listed with foreach because they are line by line.
But the answers to 10 questions of a questionnaire, for example, are registered in columns A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4, A_5, .... A_10 in a single line.

```
<?php 

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_survey_questions WHERE Poll_ID LIKE $Poll_ID order by Q_no asc");
$query->execute(); 
foreach ($query as $q) { 

 echo $q['Q_no'].") ".$q['Question']."<br>"; 

echo xxxxx; } // I need to GET and print here Q_no's answer (in A_1 column from tbl_survey_replies )
  }  ?>
```

[image: tbl_survey_questions image]

[image: tbl_survey_replies image with A_1, A_2 .... columns]

Answer (score 0):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pwd", "dbname");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

//asc is redundant
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_survey_questions WHERE Poll_ID LIKE ? order by Q_no";

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query))
{
    //i corresponding variable has type integer
    $stmt->bind_result('i', $Poll_ID);
    $stmt->execute(); 

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
    {
        echo 'PollID: '. $row['Poll_ID'] .'<br>';
    }

    $stmt->close();
}

$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: Thanks for you response Maximilian. Maybe my question is not clear. I will try to explain more my question. Poll's question's in a table with nema tbl_survey_questions. And Answer choices in seperate tables with name tbl_surves_replies. I can list questions foreach command because of listed in table line by line. But donot know how can i get user responses from tbl_survey_replies from each Poll line at columns A_1.... (A_1 columns is Q_no's answer) and other questions answer from columns. I hope question has been more understandable. Thanks for your response again.